# Why aren't all packets sent to the client?

Tags: c#, sockets, proxy, packets

I'm writing a simple proxy (more a packet logger) for an online game in C#. All the packets get received by the proxy but some aren't sent to the client (not sure about the server).
For example:

Client->Server: Login Packet - My proxy receives the packet, displays it and sends it to the server.

Server->Client: Connected! Packet - My proxy again receives the packet, it also displays it and sends it to the client.

Server->Client: Chat channels packet -  My proxy again receives the packet, it also displays it but the client doesn't receive it. There is no exception.

My code: http://lesderid.pastebin.com/Km7vT2jF

(This is the same project as here: [Why can't I send to the listening socket anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232125/why-cant-i-send-to-the-listening-socket-anymore))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just from a brief reading of the code:

1. Do not bind to `127.0.0.1`. Bind to `IPAddress.Any` instead.
2. `OnDataReceivedFromServer` needs to call `EndReceive`.
3. I don't recommend mixing synchronous (`Send`) and asynchronous (`BeginReceive`) operations on the same socket.